# How to create keys in json file using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to update a `json` file using `jq`. My json file looks like

```
{
    "A": "123",
    "B": "456",
    "C": "789",
    "D": []
}
```

Here the value for key `D` is empty so I am adding some values to it. And this is working

Now, if for some reason the key doesn't exist then I need to first create the key `D`. And I am not able to achieve this

```
{
    "A": "123",
    "B": "456",
    "C": "789",
}
```

```
cat test.json | jq 'has("D")' = false && cat test.json jq --argjson addobj '{"D": "[]"}'
```

I am getting the error

```
jq: error: Could not open file =: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file false: No such file or directory
```

expected output

```
{
    "A": "123",
    "B": "456",
    "C": "789",
    "D": []
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here

Comment: Is it always "D:[]" and "D missing" or could it also be "D:[1,2]" (or any other value)? In other words: do you always want to end up with an empty array?

Comment: Yes, if D doesn't exist then I want to create empty array "D:[]"

Comment: But what _if it exists_? Please don't answer only half of the question in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not (only) with jq, but with shell syntax.

But if all you are trying to do is to update the value of key D whether it exists or not, then you don't need any checks and can simply assign the new value:

```
$ jq '.D = ["new value"]' test.json 
{
  "A": "123",
  "B": "456",
  "C": "789",
  "D": [
    "new value"
  ]
}
```

If you want to modify the current value, the operator `|=` might be helpful.

An alternative, equivalent program would be `'. + { D: ["new value"] }'`

---

If you really want to fix your script, here's a working version of it:

```
if jq -e 'has("D")' test.json >/dev/null; then
  # key exists
  jq --argjson addobj '{"D": "[]"}' 'your program here' test.json
else
  # key doesn't exist
  jq 'your other program here'
fi
```

But this is arguably easier in jq directly:

```
jq --argjson addobj '{"D": "[]"}' '
if has("D") then
  # D exists
  . # <- your jq program
else
  # D doesn't exist
  . # <- your other jq program
end
' test.json
```

If your goal is to simply insert the key with a default value if it doesn't exist, but keep any existing value, the following simple jq program (and nothing else) should take care of that:

```
jq '{D: []} + .' test.json
```

(keys in the RHS overwrite keys from the LHS – `{a:1}+{a:2}` becomes `{a:2}`)

Objects in JavaScript (and by extension JSON), are a bag of unordered key-value pairs and `{a:1,b:2}` is the same object as `{b:2,a:1}`.

However, jq mostly keeps order of keys (although I don't think this is specified/guaranteed). So, a slightly more complicated version which puts `D` at the end of the object, but keeps existing values would be:

```
jq '.D |= (. // [])' test.json
```

Comment: Hi @knittl, thanks for the update. My goal is to conditionally check if the key exists and if not, create the key. In your solution what do you mean by "your other jq program" in the else part?

Comment: @Preeti can you edit your question to include the following: input with key, input without key, expected output for both. I'm not sure I really understand what you are trying to do (and why you need a conditional for that)

Comment: I have updated the question. All I want to do is add the key if it doesn't exist and later I will update it's value if it is empty

Comment: @Preeti my last program should take care of that just fine. Does the file always contain the value that you want to insert? If so, the first program will work too (just replace the value with whatever value you need). So, if `D` exists, will it always be the empty array or could it be another value which you would want to keep? Because if it is, you can simply overwrite it. Overwriting a value with the same value will not be different from not overwriting it; the end result is identical.

Comment: I tried your last program `jq '{D: []} + .' test.json` and modified it to `cat test.json | jq 'has("D")' = false && jq '{D: []} + .' test.json`. But this gives me `jq: error: Could not open file =: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Preeti why are you modifying it? Your shell syntax is completely wrong (see first paragraph of answer). The program already does what you are asking, no need to add additional pipes or parameters.

Comment: But simply doing `jq '{D: []} + .' test.json` doesn't add the key.

Comment: @Preeti sure it does, I tested it (again). It does not _modify_ the file (jq simply cannot do that). To modify a file, redirect the output to a new file, then move it over the old file (or use GNU sponge). Almost no Linux CLI tool modifies its input files directly; +99% of all tools consume files or standard input and write the result to standard output. Use shell IO redirection to write the output to files (not a jq question then, really)

Comment: yes "It does not modify the file (jq simply cannot do that). To modify a file, redirect the output to a new file, then move it over the old file" this was the trick. Now it is working, except the new key is added at the top instead of adding at the end. Can I make it to add at the end?

Comment: Order of keys in JSON is irrelevant; an object is an unordered bag of key-value pairs. But I'll ask again what I have commented below the question: do you always want an empty array? Or do you want to keep non-empty arrays if they are already there? In that case, there might be a way around it

Comment: Yes, I want to keep non-empty arrays if they are already there. And in case if the "D:[]" exists but empty then I will add some values to it.

Comment: @Preeti see updated answer. Btw, it would be super helpful if the question mentioned this (or used an input value which contained values and not an empty-array instead).